# WebStorm is not displaying syntax highlighting correctly

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I have somehow accidentally switched some setup related with JavaScript syntax in WebStorm and now dealing with incorrect highlighting of source attribute:
[image]

Any idea how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have injected (somehow) another language into `src` attribute.

Either

1. `Settings | Language Injections` -- find and delete unwanted injection rule.
2. <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> while having caret inside that problematic place to bring quick fix menu and choose "Uninject" from there (the injection rule will still remain, but will be deactivated; you can remove it permanently using #1)

Comment: Splendid! Yes, it was Language Injection. I had script/@src as Apple JS (global). Thank you.